# ASP.NET - adding tag obout:calender and getting error - why?

Tags: asp.net, tags, calendar, obout

I add this tag to my asp.net page (aspx):

```
<obout:Calendar runat="server"
                     ShowTimeSelector="true"
                     DateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
                     DatePickerMode="true"
                     TextBoxId="txtDate">
</obout:Calendar>
```

but i am geting this error "unrecognized tag prefix or device filter obout" what am i missing?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1.aspx) the tag prefix "obout" by adding something along these lines to the top of your page:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="obout" Namespace="OboutInc.Calendar2" Assembly="obout_Calendar2_Net" %>
```

See the [documentation here](http://www.obout.com/calendar/calendar_documentation_clientside.aspx).